# convert math equations into code with ifelse and min/max in R Studio

Tags: r, if-statement, max, min, medical

For a medical study I would like to calculate the eGFR, a measure of renal function, with an equation that require certain input values: Scr (serum creatinine), ScysC (serum cystatin C), age and sex-depending values, which are all available in my dataset.

Please see the attached image for the equations. [eGFR equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtrv9.png)

So I am mainly struggling with ifelse-statements and the min/max numbers. How do I create a code to retrieve the output with this equation?

My first thought is to create a loop function, but I don't know exactly how. So any help and time is very much appreciated :)

-EDIT-
NOTICE: it is important that the ratio between min/max is always <1. 
e.g. a female with Scr= 0.9 gives Scr/k= 0.9/0.7=1.28 and results in min=1 and max=1.28. 
A female with Scr=0.6 gives Scr/k= 0.6/0.7=0.86 and results in min=0.86 and max=1.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), AGE = c(36,36, 36), 
    CYSC = c(0.757, 1.34, 1.34), SCR = c(0.58, 0.68, 0.68), SEX = c(1,1,0)) 
        #Male = 1, Female 0

#equation:
eGFR = 135*((min(Scr/k,1)**a))*((max(Scr/k,1)**-0.601))*(min(Scysc/0.8,1)**-0.375)* (max(Scysc/0.8,1)**-0.711) * (0.995**Age) (*0.969 if female)

(With k=0.7 if F and k=0.9 if M, a=-0.248 if F and a=-0.207 if M)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `pmax` and `pmin` instead. Those are properly vectorized. And use `ifelse()` for the "if" part.

Comment: I'm confused by the structure of your dataframe. It looks like there's 7 columns, but only 5 headers. Can you provide a proper `data.frame` specification so we can help? (i.e. something like `df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2), AGE = c(36, 36), CYSC = c(3.7487, 3.3494), ... etc`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I'm guessing the structure of your data.frame. I provided how I created mine for the test since there seem to be more numbers than row.names. I also assumed that 1 is male and 0 is female. Finally, I added a third female patient for the test, with the same clinical results as male #2.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), AGE = c(36,36, 36), CYSC = c(51.614, 47.669, 47.669), SCR = c(0.75776, 1.34, 1.34), SEX = c(1,1,0))

male.idx <- df$SEX == 1

k <- rep(0.7, nrow(df))
k[male.idx] <- 0.9

a <- rep(-0.248, nrow(df))
a[male.idx] <- -0.207

eGFR <- 135*pmin(df$SCR/k,1)**a*((pmax(df$SCR/k,1)**-0.601))*(pmin(df$CYSC/0.8,1)**-0.375)* 
    (pmax(df$CYSC/0.8,1)**-0.711) * ifelse(male.idx, 0.995, 0.969)**df$AGE
```

[edited for more accurate answer]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @csgroen.

What I forgot to mention is that it is important that the ratio between min/max is always <1. 
e.g. a female with Scr= 0.9 gives Scr/k= 0.9/0.7=1.28 and results in min=1 and max=1.28. 
A female with Scr=0.6 gives Scr/k= 0.6/0.7=0.86 and results in min=0.86 and max=1.

Comment: I went back through it and min doesn't deal well with vectorization, so I used pmin instead. I believe this should work [edited the answer]